# Qual significado de "pá virada"?

Tags: significado, origem

Já escutei muita gente falando:

> Hoje acordei com a "pá virada"!

Qual significado de "pá virada"? De onde surgiu essa expressão?

Comment: Somente alguém muito doido, enérgico e animado conseguiria usar uma pá virada.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

A expressão mais antiga parece ser *(ser) **da pá virada***; já se encontra em 1853 e vem nos dicionários. O [Aulete (verbete *pá*)](http://www.aulete.com.br/p%C3%A1) diz:

> **Da pá virada**
>   **1** Pop. Bras. Diz-se de algo ou alguém que foge dos padrões habituais por ser brincalhão e provocador, ou imprevisível e impetuoso, ou amalucado etc.

O Houaiss (Lisboa, 2003) diz mais ou menos a mesma coisa:

> **pá** […] **da pá virada** *Brasil, informal* diz-se do que é buliçoso, brincalhão ou desordeiro, turbulento ou licencioso, debochado <*uma peça da pá virada*>  <*ela é da pá virada*>

O exemplo mais antigo que encontrei é de [Antonio José de Cega-rega, *Uma Contradança de Velhacos* (Rio de Janeiro, 1853)](https://books.google.pt/books?id=IybzxT36BdAC&pg=PA21&dq=%22p%C3%A1%20virada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi5_sjvqePVAhVLWBoKHVuECdg4ZBDoAQjCAjAv#v=onepage&q=%22p%C3%A1%20virada%22&f=false); diz-se que um certo inglês que causa problemas “é da pá virada” (grafia original, negrito meu):

> L. M. […] mas é preciso levar as cousas com moderação, principalmente por causa de um tal lord Palmerston, que é **da pá virada**, e tem a mania de ser liberal.
>   V. A esse é que eu tambem queria que se cortasse a lingua; V. Ex. não poderia fazer alguma cousa a tal respeito?
>   L. M. Nada, não senhor, que esse é inglez, e manda por aqui uns taes navios de guerra, que tem feito diabruras, e até nos fizerão brigar com os negociantes de escravos […] e é homem de todos os diabos, manda para ca navios e põe tudo em polverosa.

E há gente “da pá virada” com impulsos assassinos. Veja-se esta [“Canconeta” de Arthur Azevedo, incluída em Mello Moraes Filho, *Serenatas e Saráus* (Rio de Janeiro, 1902)](https://archive.org/stream/serenatasesarus01moragoog#page/n308/mode/2up); “alfacinha” é provavelmente ‘uma liboeta’ (os lisboetas são conhedidos por *alfacinhas*):

> A fluminense é mimosa
>   Florinha meiga e gentil,
>   A alfacinha é impetuosa,
>   No proprio amor varonil ;
>   Morre aquella apaixonada
>   Se um homem lhe causa mal
>   Esta no gajo, irritada,
>   Cravaria um bom punhal!
>
> E' **da pá virada** !
>   Não ha outra igual

Ou este [“Recordações de Viagens”, publicado na revista Kósmos em 1908 (p. 43 do PDF):](http://memoria.bn.br/pdf/146420/per146420_1908_00009.pdf)

> O noivo é **da *pá virada***, vancê bem sabe.
>   Já mandou p'ra outra vida aquelle camarada capenga, que lhe respondeu mal e bateu a mão na *branca*.

Este uso mantém-se até ao presente, mas entretanto, mais recentemente (só encontrei a partir de 1974) aparece também *(estar, andar, acordar, amanhecer) **com a pá virada***. Nalguns casos, *estar com a pá virada* significa simplesmente que a pessoa, não sendo por natureza “da pá virada”, se encontra momentaneamente nesse estado—é a diferença habitual entre *ser* e *estar*:

> —Mais, Filó, ocê oviu a charanga dela? Nossa Mãe!... A véia [‘velha’] tá **co’a pá virada** ! Inté parecia possuída dus demonho.
>   [Wilson de Lima Bastos, *Sob o Signo da Esperança*, 1977.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=RdQJAQAAIAAJ&q=%22a%20p%C3%A1%20virada%22&dq=%22a%20p%C3%A1%20virada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjJ7q69p-XVAhVD2BoKHTxjApYQ6AEIkwEwEA)
>
> Se a cozinheira soubesse que para francês caracol é comida chique e que branco não come bicho-de-pau, diria que o mundo tá **com a pá virada.**
>   [Renato Pompeu, *Samba-Enredo*, 1982.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=u1ItAAAAYAAJ&q=%22com%20a%20p%C3%A1%20virada%22&dq=%22com%20a%20p%C3%A1%20virada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwil0-3NpOXVAhUEAxoKHU9EBZoQ6AEIlAEwEQ)

Mas noutros casos, especialmente com *acordar* ou *amanhecer*, parece querer dizer que a pessoa acordou indisposta ou talvez irritadiça:

> Mas hoje amanheci **com a pá virada**. Se carece falar mais esprivitado, explico: o estambo [‘estômago’] vira e revira, embrulha como coisa que revoltado, querendo por o avêsso à mostra.
>   [José Antunes de Lima, *Capoeirão*, 1974.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=aLstAAAAYAAJ&q=%22a%20p%C3%A1%20virada%22&dq=%22a%20p%C3%A1%20virada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi9x_rXruPVAhWJ0xoKHd0uCuIQ6AEIqwEwFA)
>
> Em alguma manhã você acorda **com a pá virada**, o dia desanda e quase nada dá certo.
>   [*Entre Livros*, 2005.](https://books.google.pt/books?id=60MnAQAAIAAJ&q=%22a%20p%C3%A1%20virada%22&dq=%22a%20p%C3%A1%20virada%22&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj1jICg4eXVAhWDXhoKHZsBAB8Q6AEIWjAH)

---

### Sobre a origem

Quanto à origem, a conclusão que eu tiro para mim é: não se sabe. Em vários sites na net diz-se que e expressão se inspira na pá que quando “está virada para baixo, voltada para o solo, está inútil, abandonada pelo homem vagabundo, irresponsável, parasita” (ver por exemplo [aqui](http://www.oarquivo.com.br/variedades/curiosidades/2830-a-origem-de-alguns-ditados-populares.html)). Este texto e outros muito semelhantes repetem-se em vários sites, mas nenhum deles explica como é que sabe isto, nem apresenta quaisquer fontes bibliográficas. Ademais, eu encontrei *da pá virada* apenas com o significado de ‘desordeiro, impetuoso, agressivo’, nunca no de ‘inútil’ ou ‘vagabundo’.

O [Wikcionário diz que *pá virada*](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/da_p%C3%A1_virada) é uma corruptela da expressão gaúcha [*aspa virada* (Wikcionário)](https://pt.wiktionary.org/wiki/aspa_virada), que teria o mesmo significado. *Aspa virada* parece-me ser uma variante relativamente pouco comum de *aspa torta*, também uma expressão gaúcha, que segundo os dicionários ([Aulete](http://www.aulete.com.br/aspa), [Michaelis](http://michaelis.uol.com.br/busca?r=0&f=0&t=0&palavra=aspa)) significa ‘zangado, mal-humorado’. Mas no Wiktionário também não nos explicam como é que sabem que *da pá virada* vem de *aspa virada*.

Há também uma povoação chamada [*Pá Virada* (Wikipédia)](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vertente_do_L%C3%A9rio), município de Vertente do Lério, Pernambuco. Não sei se as pessoas da Pá Virada alguma vez tiveram fama de serem “da pá virada”.

Comment: Poderia ter origem nas pás da hélice de um pequeno avião? Se estiverem viradas o avião iria para trás, o que seria uma pegadinha e tanto!

Comment: Um avião dom as pás da hélice ao contrário seria verdadeiramente da pá virada. Mas a expressão já estava em uso em 1853, antes de haver aviões.

Answer (score 2):

O primeiro significado é *sem nenhuma serventia*. Sua origem é devido a pá de pedreiro virada não ter utilidade.

É uma expressão Brasileiro com sua origem no século 19.

Atualmente, é usada com outros significados, como *criança travessa ou inquieta*.

Fonte: [Guia do Estudante - Abril](http://origin.guiadoestudante.abril.com.br/aventuras-historia/pa-virada-436077.shtml)

Answer (score -1):

Não poderia ser uma derivação da palavra "Depravada" Da pá virada

Comment: Boas-vindas ao Portuguese SE! Obrigado pela contribuição, mas por favor note que geralmente se esperam respostas bem fundamentadas — por exemplo com referências. Sua suposição é interessante mas precisaria ser substanciada.